# Setting / Getting System Variables on Azure Web Roles

Tags: php, azure, iis, environment-variables, azure-web-roles

I can't believe I am the only person to have come across this issue, but I am not able to find anything about it anywhere.

We currently have some Azure Web Roles running our app, and for security I decided to put credentials like usernames, passwords and API keys in the System Environment Variables, and get them in my PHP scripts using `getenv()`.

We are running Windows Server Web Roles with IIS and PHP installed. I am using a startup task in my `ServiceDefinition.csdef` like so:

```
<Startup>
  <Task commandLine="setEnvironmentVariables.cmd" executionContext="elevated" />
</Startup>
```

The contents of the `cmd` file simply sets the environment variables when the web role is spun up.

So far so good. However I know from experience on our windows dev server, that in order for PHP scripts to see newly added environment variables, you have to run `IISReset`, you can then see them using `getenv()`.

However you cannot run `IISReset` on Azure web roles, as per this document here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/iis-reset-on-windows-azure-web-role/

So my scripts cannot see the variables!! Am I missing something, or is there an easier way to set the system environment variables when the web role starts so that PHP can see them?

Comment: have you considered setting environment variables using app settings?

Comment: @4c74356b41 App settings? There aren't any App Settings using Cloud Services Web Roles / Worker Roles... I think you are talking about Azure Web Apps

Comment: oh sorry, I misread the title

Answer (score 0):

The [ConfigurationSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg557553.aspx#ConfigurationSettings) element in your Cloud Configuration for the WebRole will allow you define settings. And by the way change those settings without re-compile and re-deploy your role.

The second most important element for your case is the [Environment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg557553.aspx#Environment), which enables you to define Environment variables.

And you can initialise an Environment Variable with the value of a Configuration setting using the [RoleInstanceValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg557553.aspx#RoleInstanceValue) element which should be child of Value.

For how to construct the XPATH for RoleInstanceValue you can consult the [XPath Cheat Sheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-role-config-xpath).

But at the end, I will ask you why you still develop WebRole instead of using Web Apps and App Service Plans, where you can manage the AppSettings and ConnectionStrings direcrly in the WebApp in Azure and strip those completely out of web.config? The only obvious reason for me - usage of 3rd party APIs/Components which are not compatible with Web Apps (like requirements to run an installer, or usage of COM compontents).

Comment: Forgive me if I am misunderstanding, but I thought this was just for creating variables that can be accessed by start up tasks. I want PHP on the webrole(once it is up and running) to be able to access the system environment variables.

Comment: If you follow all the links in my answer, you will see that you can create **environment variables** based on the values of **configuration settings**. Plus, configuration settings are accessible not only from the startup tasks, but also from the Code. Unfortunatelly only .NET and Java code. To my knowledge, there is no PHP SDK/API to access the Cloud Configuration Settings. But you can create Environment Variables based on the Configuration Settings. Check the [Environment element in Cloud Configuration Schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg557553.aspx#Environment)

Comment: The environment variables are set within the runtime path of the Cloud Configuration Settings, which says `The Runtime element is only available using the Azure SDK version 1.3 or higher.`... So which SDK will I need? It only seems to be available in the .NET version?